# connect reactjs with odoo

Tags: reactjs, odoo

I have installed the `odoo-react` package to connect to my Odoo application and I create this function to login

```
const login = () => {
    const odoo = new Odoo({
      host: url,
      port: 8069,
      database: db,
      username: userName,
      password: password,
    });

    odoo
      .authenticate()
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };
```

but when I use this function I have the issue of cors policy and the request was blocked in the server, also when I test the API in postman it works

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score -1):

for me best practice is to use node with POSTGRES to build full Rest API and then from node to react, and you could use tool like postman to test.

Comment: do think  connect the odoo with espress is the best solution

Comment: yes ofcourse, is the best, and you can also use a axios fetch data

Comment: but how can i do this can you help me please